# React-Native - Section List by key

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm looking to display a list of items divided into sections in ReactNative

The data is received from the database as a flat array with key for each item - for example:

```
[{'key':'movie','name':'ToyStory1'},
 {'key':'movie','name':'ToyStory2'},
 {'key':'tv','name':'X-Files'},
 {'key':'tv','name':'Big bang theory'}]
```

I want to stay with a flat array.

All the solution I found so far working with this kind of data:

```
[{'key':'movie, 'data':[{'name':'ToyStory1'},{'name':'ToyStory2'}]},
 {'key':'tv, 'data':[{'name':'X-Files'},{'name':'Big bang theory'}]}
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can map over your data and insert "header" objects at appropriate places.

```js
const data = [
  { 'key': 'movie', 'name': 'ToyStory1' },
  { 'key': 'movie', 'name': 'ToyStory2' },
  { 'key': 'tv', 'name': 'X-Files' },
  { 'key': 'tv', 'name': 'Big bang theory' }
];

// preprocess data to insert header objects
const dataWithHeadersInserted = data => data.reduce((res, item) => {
  if (item.key !== res.header) {
    res.header = item.key;
    res.data.push({ header: res.header });
  }
  res.data.push(item);
  return res;
}, {
  header: null,
  data: [],
}).data;

const processedData = dataWithHeadersInserted(data);

console.log(processedData);

// later map over preprocessed data and render correct component
// here in React you would use map and return components 
// instead of forEach and console.log
processedData.forEach(item => {
  if (item.header) {
    console.log('====== Header', item.header, '======');
  } else {
    console.log(item.name);
  }
});
```

If you don't care to preprocess your data you can also do it on the fly:

```js
const data = [
  { 'key': 'movie', 'name': 'ToyStory1' },
  { 'key': 'movie', 'name': 'ToyStory2' },
  { 'key': 'tv', 'name': 'X-Files' },
  { 'key': 'tv', 'name': 'Big bang theory' }
];
     
const dataWithHeadersOnFly = data => {
  let header = null;

  // In react this would be a map instead
  return data.forEach(item => {
    if (item.key !== header) {
      header = item.key;
      
      // In react you would return a Fragment with header and item components
      console.log('====== Header', header, '======');
      console.log(item.name);
      return;
    }

    // In react you would just return item component
    console.log(item.name);
  });
};

dataWithHeadersOnFly(data);
```

```
const DataWithHeadersOnFly = ({data, renderSectionHeader, renderItem}) => {
  return data.map((item, index, dataArr) => (
    <Fragment>
      {(!dataArr[index - 1] || dataArr[index - 1].key !== item.key) && 
        renderSectionHeader({ header: item.key, index })}
      {renderItem({ item, index })}
    </Fragment>
  ));
};

...

render() {
  return (
    <DataWithHeadersOnFly
      data={data}
      renderSectionHeader={({ header, index }) => (
        <h3 key={`header-${header}-${index}`}>
          ====== {header} ======
        </h3>
      )}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <div key={`${item.name}-${index}`}>{item.name}</div>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit beautiful-snyder-5jids]

Comment: Actually, I would like to avoid changing the array and looking for a UI component that can solve this.

Comment: Neither of these mutate the original array, map/reduce return new objects. AFAIK you will probably have to roll your own component to selectively render sections.

Comment: @DrewReese- this is what I'm looking for, a UI component

Comment: I thought it a simple exercise to take the algorithm and make a react component; I've amended my solution to include a running codesandbox.  FYI, a generic component like this generally is not going to exist for the simple fact that it is heavily coupled to your data schema.  Also note, if you want to wrap each "section" in a semantic tag you may have to use a nested structure similar to your question,

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a function to return filtered array of objects Like this

```
function filteredData(recievedData, key)
    { 
       var dataperKey = recievedData.filter(function (el) {
        return el.key == key
      });
      return dataperKey;
    }
```

This function will return filtered array on the basis of the key you pass for example if you pass **movie** as a `key` then output will be

```
[{'key':'movie','name':'ToyStory1'},
 {'key':'movie','name':'ToyStory2'}]
```

So now to create your **sections** data for `SectionList

```
sections={[{'key':'movie, 'data':filteredData(recievedData,'movie')},
 {'key':'tv, 'data':filteredData(recievedData,'tv')}
]}
```